# How to use sterio Camera with two images in the same frame

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, bandwidth

I bought a stereo synchronized camera where the two images (left and right) are together in the same frame.

My application was written in **java** using **OpenCV 3.1.0**, my computer is a macbook pro 2014.

When my application freezes when it executes this line

```
New VideoCapture (1);
```

Would the problem be related to bandwidth? Does anyone know a way to solve this problem?

Camera Specs:

Model: KYT-U100-960R1 Sensor: Aptina AR0130 Focus: Manual Synchronization: Yes Resolution & frame : 1280X480 MJPEG 30fps, YUY2 15fps 2560X960 MJPEG 30fps, YUY2 5fps Compression format: MJPEG \ YUY2 Interface: USB2.0 Lens Parameter : lens 3.6mm(2.1/2.8/6/8/12/16mm, fisheye optional), 30-180 degree optional Voltage: DC5V USB Video Class(UVC): Support Auto exposure AEC: Support Auto white blance AEB: Support Adjustable parameters: Brightness/Contrast/Color saturation/Definition/Gamma/WB Dimension: 93mm x 27mm, 74mm x 27mm optional, other size can be customized as well Operating Temperature: -20°C to 70°C Support OS: Windows, Linux, MAC, Android

Comment: I have experienced similar problems when trying to hook up multiple webcams at once - in my case it was a limitation of RAM. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I do not think this is the problem, I have 16gb on my mac. I already tested the camera on a windows 7 with 8gb using an application called AMcap and the camera works. Maybe you have a library that will help me solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't a library to help you, I still think RAM could be an issue though. I needed around 12Gb to handle more than 4 cameras, and they were at lower resolution than 1280px. When you say it freezes, does the display freeze only, or does all behaviour (all application threads) freeze completely?

Comment: I'm using opencv with java. Java is just a wrap that uses jni to make calls to opencv methods written in C ++. When I say freeze I mean the method is called, but no return. It's how the application expects the response of the method that never arrives. The operating system continues to function properly. I already had success creating a stereo vision camera using two separate usb cameras. I will check the memory of my computer when the application is running. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck. Please post your solution when you figure it out.